# R function for creating, naming and lagging variables

Tags: r, function, lag

I have some data like so:

```
a <- c(1, 2, 9, 18, 6, 45)
b <- c(12, 3, 34, 89, 108, 44)
c <- c(0.5, 3.3, 2.4, 5, 13,2)

df <- data.frame(a, b,c)
```

I need to create a function to lag a lot of variables at once for a very large time series analysis with dozens of variables. So i need to lag a lot of variables without typing it all out.  In short, I would like to create variables `a.lag1`, `b.lag1` and `c.lag1` and be able to add them to the original `df` specified above.  I figure the best way to do so is by creating a custom function, something along the lines of:

```
lag.fn <- function(x) {
    assign(paste(x, "lag1", sep = "."), lag(x, n = 1L)
    return (assign(paste(x, "lag1", sep = ".")
}
```

The desired output is:

```
a.lag1 <- c(NA, 1, 2, 9, 18, 6, 45)
b.lag1 <- c(NA, 12, 3, 34, 89, 108, 44)
c.lag1 <- c(NA, 0.5, 3.3, 2.4, 5, 13, 2)
```

However, I don't get what I am looking for.  Should I change the environment to the global environment?  I would like to be able to use `cbind` to add to orignal `df`.  Thanks.

Comment: your `a` and `c`  have 6 elements each while `b` has 5

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: @Onyambu just added desired output.  I have a lot of variables i want to do this to at one time hence i am trying a user defined function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `mutate_all`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   mutate_all(funs(lag = lag(.)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Easy using `dplyr`. Don't call data frames `df`, may cause confusion with the function of the same name. I'm using `df1`.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(a.lag1 = lag(a),
         b.lag1 = lag(b),
         c.lag1 = lag(c))
```

Answer (score 2):

The data frame statement in the question is invalid since `a`, `b` and `c` are not the same length.  What you can do is create a zoo series.  Note that the lag specified in `lag.zoo` can be a vector of lags as in the second example below.

```
library(zoo)

z <- merge(a = zoo(a), b = zoo(b), c = zoo(c))
lag(z, -1)  # lag all columns

lag(z, 0:-1)  # each column and its lag
```

Answer (score 1):

If everything else fails, you can use a simple base R function:

```
my_lag <- function(x, steps = 1) {
  c(rep(NA, steps), x[1:(length(x) - steps)])
}
```